# After adding border unwanted scroll appears

Tags: html, css, autocomplete, scrollbar, angular-material

I use autocomplete widget [mdAutocomplete](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete) from Angular Material.

Currently scrollbar appears if list contains more than 6 elements.

[image]

But when I add a border to md-virtual-repeat-container

> md-virtual-repeat-container {
>     border: 1px solid red;
>   }

scroll always appears, even for 2 elements.

I don't want to have a scroll-bar when number of elements in the list is less than 6.
I've already tried `overflow: hidden;` and it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: try to define box-sizing: `md-virtual-repeat-container { border: 1px solid red; box-sizing: border-box;}`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't change anything :(

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box !important;` too?

Comment: Still no difference.

Comment: could you give a link to alive page with that issue?